# Colorbox with royal slider. Open at specific slide only after close and open colorbox

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm using Colorbox with Royal slider. 
The problem I have is that I want to open the Colorbox and slide to a specific slide in Royal slider from a list of thumbnails.
I have it working ... sort of .... Problem is that it only works if i first open Conolbox and then close it. Second time it opens and slide to correct slide.

My jQuery and javascript knowledge is rather limited ;)

Links to open colorbox looks like this

```
<a href="produkter2.html#2"  class="colorboxSlider">
```

And the colorbox and royal slider code looks like this

```
var win = $(window),
  w,
  cContent = $('#cboxLoadedContent'),
  currRs;
$('#produkter ul li').on('click', '.colorboxSlider', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.colorbox({
      preloading: true,
      modal: false,
      transition: 'none',
      speed: 0,      
      onComplete: function(e) {
        currRs = $('#cboxLoadedContent').find('.royalSlider').royalSlider({
          imageScaleMode: 'fill',
          keyboardNavEnabled: true,

          deeplinking: {
        // deep linking options go gere
        enabled: true,
        change:true,
        prefix: ''
    },          
        }).data('royalSlider');


$("#s2 a").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
currRs.goTo(2);
});

$("#s1 a").on("click", function(e){
e.preventDefault();
currRs.goTo(1);
});


updateLightboxSize();


      },
      href:$(this).attr('href'),
  });

  return false;
});
```

I know its may be because the "currRS" does not exist when clicking the first time. But I don't have any idea how to get that into the onComplete: function.